# How are regular expressions implemented in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, performance, grep

I have just read this [interesting article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) about the implementation details for various languages that support regular expressions.

It describes an alternative implementation of regular expressions that uses non-deterministic finite automatons (NFAs) versus deterministic ones (DFAs).  It claims that back-tracking DFA implementations (the version used in Perl, Java, and others) are susceptible to very slow performance on some particularly "pathological" regular expressions.  (grep, awk, and Tcl still use DFAs, but somehow are exponentially faster)

It makes no reference to the .NET framework, but I would like to know how .NET (C# in particular) regular expressions are implemented, and how they compare in terms of performance.

**Edit:**

Can I assume since the answerer's article mentions .NET does backtracking, that it will be on par with Perl and Java?

Comment: FYI, there's only .NET Regular expressions, not C# and VB.NET regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks John - I had a hunch it was a single codebase, but wasn't sure if C# exposed anything that VB didn't.

Comment: Just offtopic but related to the comment: afaik, .NET is coded in C#. :P But I can see where someone would get confused by that.

Comment: Maybe you could specify which framework? You can watch Mono's implementation at http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System/System.Text.RegularExpressions/

Comment: If you want to turn off backtracking, you can always just do it with +? and *?. Though usually I try to fix those issues by changing the pattern.

Comment: Lazy quantifiers like +? and *? don't turn off backtracking.  They simply reverse the order in which the alternatives are attempted.  (Backtracking means to go back to a preceding token in the regular expression.  It's still backtracking even if it causes the match to be expanded rather than reduced.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an *awesome* write-up [here](http://www.moserware.com/2009/03/how-net-regular-expressions-really-work.html). He takes advantage of the fact that you can step in to the .NET framework code and see what it does, and explains how everything works. It's an excellent read.

Comment: ...written by SO denizen Jeff Moser.